# Build Failed in Visual Studio 2019 for Angular Application

Tags: angular, visual-studio, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, visual-studio-2019

I made application of Angular 8 and .Net Core 2.2 (Web API) with Visual Studio 2019 (Community Edition). To Keep both the project in single solution I followed the instruction given in this link:
[Add angular 7.0 client application to asp.net core 2.2 web api project](https://medium.com/@rohit_ramname/add-angular-7-0-client-application-to-asp-net-core-2-2-web-api-project-ce1617d1d38d)

It is working perfectly for sometime and now giving build error as below image. Whereas i can run the application with ng serve command from command prompt but cannot build with Visual Studio 2019.

[image]

I tried to solve error by changing settings in tsconfig.json but not succeeded so far. Find my current tsconfig.json as below:

```js
{
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es2015",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ]
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "fullTemplateTypeCheck": false,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true
  }
}
```

Please help for the above case. I don't know how to share code but i can share the code as its just learning app.

Second, is there any other way to keep both Angular & .Net Core Web Api in single project?

Comment: build faild because you have a error in html or ts file. i think you have use variable in html file but variable is not define in a ts file.

Comment: @upinderkumar No that is not the case. I can run application with ngserve command without any error.

Answer (score 5):

Found the solution. I have excluded "ClientApp" folder which is for Angular and tried to build the solution which have only now Web Api project. Still its giving me same error. So its confirmed that there is no issue in tsconfig.json.

I changed the content of my .csproj file as below:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.2</TargetFramework>
    <AspNetCoreHostingModel>InProcess</AspNetCoreHostingModel>
    <TypeScriptCompileBlocked>true</TypeScriptCompileBlocked>
    <TypeScriptToolsVersion>Latest</TypeScriptToolsVersion>
    <TypeScriptExperimentalDecorators>True</TypeScriptExperimentalDecorators>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Before it was like below:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.2</TargetFramework>
    <AspNetCoreHostingModel>InProcess</AspNetCoreHostingModel>
    <TypeScriptToolsVersion>3.6</TypeScriptToolsVersion>
   <TypeScriptExperimentalDecorators>True</TypeScriptExperimentalDecorators>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely host .Net Core WebApi and Angular in one solution. Microsoft even created a not so bad project template that is included since .Net Core 2.2. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/spa/angular?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio for a good starting point.

The article you listed was for an existing, standalone, Web Api project not built using the Angular SPA template, where they needed to add the SPA later. Microsoft's SPA template is not bad and everything works out of the box, try it.